# How to test PayPal Form payment ? (CSC required)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

I integrated the Paypal payment using html form (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/)

Now I want try to purchase something, so I created a new PayPal personal account and after I created a sandbox test account.
[image]

(doesn't display the csc number).

When I try to buy something on my site, it send me on Paypal to complete the purchase, but if I try to login with the sandbox test account, paypal says that the credentials aren't valid, instead if I used my standard credentials what credit card have to use to test ?
I tried http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/ with ccv 123 but don't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it's telling you that your credentials aren't valid then you need to fix your credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just because I used the live url on the form post method, the correct one to use to test is:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```